# What is this font used in Realm of the Mad God?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I am trying to replicate the font in this picture:

[image]

I have searched extensively for this  font (the upper red font of the damage). If someone could point this font out to me, that would be great!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot for more of the number? Every additional glyph gives more hints about what it might be.

Comment: It's entirely possible it is a custom font.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying a font.

Comment: @Ktash, yes give me a second... Though you can just type up realm of the mad god in google, and click on images, and ta da!

Comment: @cloudymusic We allow this type of question so long as it contains a screenshot. [More info here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5082/15643)

Comment: @ZenOfPython I found a few and used that to identify the font in my answer.

Comment: @Ktash Interesting, I wouldn't have guessed that we allowed it, being that fonts aren't really unique to games. Works for me, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font seems to be [Myriad](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/myriad) by Adobe. Specifically, it looks like the bold or semibold form of the family. Myriad Pro is close as well, but has some differences.